# Decenter an image on python

Tags: python, image, turtle-graphics

I'd like to decenter an image on my program. I set my border to -230, -300 as you can see but the image I put as the background is being centered. I'd like to put it within the border.

```
    #SET UP WINDOW
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.bgcolor("black")
    wn.title("x")
    wn.setup(width=800, height=800)
    wn.bgpic("spacebg.png")


    #DRAW GAME BORDER
    border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
    border_pen.speed(0)
    border_pen.color("white")
    border_pen.penup()
    border_pen.setposition(-230, -300)
    border_pen.pendown()
    border_pen.pensize(3)
    for side in range(4):
        border_pen.fd(600)
        border_pen.lt(90)
    border_pen.hideturtle()
```

Comment: What is the resolution of your spacebg.png? Maybe you need to pad it to be 800 by 800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the image is always centered on `(0, 0)`, we can use `setworldcoordinates()` to change where `(0, 0)` is located:

```
import turtle

# SET UP WINDOW
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('black')
wn.title("x")
wn.setup(width=800, height=800)
wn.setworldcoordinates(-470, -400, 330, 400)  # 70 pixel shift
wn.bgpic("spacebg.png")

# DRAW GAME BORDER
border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.speed('fastest')
border_pen.color('white')
border_pen.pensize(3)

border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300, -300)
border_pen.pendown()

for side in range(4):
    border_pen.fd(600)
    border_pen.lt(90)

border_pen.hideturtle()

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I found this solution a few hours after I posted my request.  I struggled to understand how the coordinates worked though!